# Clavamox possible overdose

Tags: cats, health, medicines

My 15 year old female cat is being treated for suspected UTI.  62.5 mg tablet twice daily (every 12 hours).  Despite sitting with her for 1/2 hour to make sure she didn't expel it, and I was sure she had swallowed it, I found a dry perfectly formed tablet stuck at the back of her cat blanket.  If this was tonight's, I am alarmed because today I found one entangled in her white fur on her leg.

I was afraid to use that because instructions warn not to remove from foil until ready to use.

- If this is not tonight's and I give it to her, would an excess dose be dangerous?
- What if it is older than tonight? Is the fact it's been opened for a time dangerous?
- Should I just continue for the rest of the prescription & pray the 2 missed tablets won't be too serious?

Comment: Please read the package leaflet of the tablets or ask the vet who gave you the tablets for this specific information. Usually you continue treatment as if the tablet was swallowed, but again, you should always observe the information given by the manufacturer.